# Finding all the possible combinations based on the presence or not of data in the rows

Tags: r, combinations, multiple-columns

I'm working with a large data frame where there are many empty rows (NA) in columns called Ion Score. Basically, this score is the identification of certain proteins.

The general structure of my data frame is:

```
N | Accession |  Ion Score1    | Ion Score2 | Ion Score3 | 
1 | 4322      |  5             | 5          | 5          | 
2 | 2344      |  5             | NA         | 5          | 
3 | 2341      |  NA            | 5          | NA         |   
4 | 2346      |  NA            | NA         | 5          |   
5 | 2346      |  5             | NA         | NA         |  
6 | 2348      |  NA            |  5         | 5          |  
7 | 2349      |  5             | 5          | NA         |
```

What I would like to have is something like this:

```
df1:
N | Accession |  Ion Score1    | Ion Score2 | Ion Score3 | 
1 | 4322      |  5             | 5          | 5          | 

df2:
N | Accession |  Ion Score1    | Ion Score2 | Ion Score3 |
2 | 2349      |  5             | 5          | NA         | 

df3: 
N | Accession |  Ion Score1    | Ion Score2 | Ion Score3 |
3 | 2344      |  5             | NA         | 5          |  

df4:
N | Accession |  Ion Score1    | Ion Score2 | Ion Score3 |
5 | 2347      |  NA            | NA         | 5          |  
.
. 
.
```

and so on, taking into account all possible combinations.

A more illustrative example would be this, in the case of obtaining a data table with all the possible combinations:

```
N | Accession |  Ion Score1    | Ion Score2 | Ion Score3 | 
1 | 4322      |  5             | 5          | 5          | 
2 | 2349      |  5             | 5          | NA         | 
3 | 2344      |  5             | NA         | 5          |   
4 | 2348      |  NA            | 5          | 5          | 
5 | 2347      |  NA            | NA         | 5          | 
6 | 2341      |  NA            | 5          | NA         | 
7 | 2349      |  5             | NA         | NA         |
```

In order to make it clearer, in this way I can see which are common to three, common to two and those that are only in a sample.

I thought that the best way was using combination in R.
and then try to filter, sort and group the columns.

Firstly I used this in order to know how many combinations are possible

```
#Where N is the number of combinations, in this case 3. 
Combination_table <- data.frame(expand.grid(rep(list(0:1), 19))) 
#invert row order
Combination_table <- Combination_table[-nrow(Combination_table), ]
```

And then filter following the combinations and create a new data frame:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Proteins[!is.na(Proteins$Ion Score) &
                               !is.na(Proteins$Ion Score2) &
                               !is.na(Proteins$Ion Score3), ])
df2 <- data.frame(Proteins[!is.na(Proteins$Ion Score) &
                               is.na(Proteins$Ion Score2) &
                               !is.na(Proteins$Ion Score3), ])
df3 <- data.frame(Proteins[!is.na(Proteins$Ion Score) &
                               !is.na(Proteins$Ion Score2) &
                               is.na(Proteins$Ion Score3), ])
df4 <- data.frame(Proteins[is.na(Proteins$Ion Score) &
                               is.na(Proteins$Ion Score2) &
                               !is.na(Proteins$Ion Score3), ])
.
.
.
```

etc.

This works perfectly, the problem is when I have many Ion Score columns. For example, 9 Ion Score columns = 512 possible combinations.

Do you know another way to do this?

Example data set:

```
Proteins <- data.frame(N = c(1, 2, 3, 4), Accession = c(4322, 
    222, 2344, 2341), `Ion Score1` = c(5, 5, "NA", "NA"), `Ion Score2` = c(5, 
    "NA", 5, 5), `Ion Score3` = c(5, 5, "NA", 5))
```

EDIT:

```
N | Accession |  Ion Score1    | Ion Score2 | Ion Score3 | 
1 | 4322      |  3             | 51         | 12          | 
2 | 4533      |  7             | NA         | 87          | 
3 | 4125      |  NA            | 9          | NA          |  
4 | 8964      |  NA            | 9          | NA          |  
5 | 5454      |  NA            | 10         | NA         |  
6 | 9871      |  6             | 5          | NA          |  
7 | 7562      |  NA            | 5          | NA          |   
8 | 7894      |  8             | NA         | 5           |   
9 | 0189      |  5             | NA         | NA          |  
10| 8746      |  NA            |  45        | 54          |  
11| 8746      |  5             | 23          | NA         |
```

Example:

```
Proteins <- data.frame(N = c(1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11), Accession = c(4322,222, 2344, 2341,6598,98974,7889,78798,1212,4566,1148), `Ion Score1` = c(3, 7, "NA", "NA","NA",6,"NA",8,5,"NA",5), `Ion Score2` = c(51, "NA",9,9,10,5,5,"NA","NA",45, 23), `Ion Score3` = c(12,87,"NA","NA","NA","NA","NA", 5, "NA", 54,"NA"))
```

Comment: Combinations of what? It is not very clear. Please also post expected outcome

Comment: @Sotos combinations without repetition. I mean for example: Having this letters, A, B,C... Find the possible combinations. So, this should be: ABC, AB, AC and BC. This is what I'm doing in this example, compare all the possible combinations between 3 examples.

Comment: No, I know what combinations are :) I was asking about what you are combining

Comment: @Sotos I am combining the data of Ion Score. This number means the  presence or absence of proteins in the sample. If there's a number in the Ion Score column, this means that there's a protein. If there isn't (NA), this means that there isn't a protein.

Comment: @Sotos For example, in the first row you can see 5 | 5 | 5. This means that there's a protein in the three examples. In the next row you can see: 5 | 5 | NA. This means that there's a protein in the example 1 and 2 but not in 3.

Comment: @Sotos does this address your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `expand.grid()`, which you can use to make a lookup table of all combinations (which I call `x2` here). Then, I loop over all combinations (i.e., `nrow(x2)`) and extract matching rows of the data frame.

```r
Proteins <- data.frame(N = c(1, 2, 3, 4), Accession = c(4322, 
    222, 2344, 2341), `Ion Score1` = c(5, 5, NA, NA), `Ion Score2` = c(5, 
    NA, 5, 5), `Ion Score3` = c(5, 5, NA, 5), stringsAsFactors = F)

cols <- 3  # Number of 'Ion Score' columns

# make a grid of all combinations
x1 <- do.call(rep, args = list(list(c(1, NA)), cols))
x2 <- as.matrix(expand.grid(x1))

head(x2)
#>      Var1 Var2 Var3
#> [1,]    1    1    1
#> [2,]   NA    1    1
#> [3,]    1   NA    1
#> [4,]   NA   NA    1
#> [5,]    1    1   NA
#> [6,]   NA    1   NA

for (ii in seq_len(nrow(x2))) {
    idx <- apply(Proteins[, 3:5], 1, function(x) {
        isTRUE(all.equal(is.na(x), is.na(x2[ii, ]), check.attributes = FALSE, use.names = FALSE))
    })
    if (any(idx))
        assign(paste0("df", ii), Proteins[idx, ])
}

df1
#>   N Accession Ion.Score1 Ion.Score2 Ion.Score3
#> 1 1      4322          5          5          5
df2
#>   N Accession Ion.Score1 Ion.Score2 Ion.Score3
#> 4 4      2341         NA          5          5
df3
#>   N Accession Ion.Score1 Ion.Score2 Ion.Score3
#> 2 2       222          5         NA          5
df6
#>   N Accession Ion.Score1 Ion.Score2 Ion.Score3
#> 3 3      2344         NA          5         NA
```

Note that I changed the `Proteins` data set and made numeric variables instead of factors of strings as in your example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I use your example with numbers or a strings?. The number 5 is just an example and the number of columns can be more or less than this example. In fact, I'm trying to apply your answer in a data frame of 19 columns.

Comment: Can you be more explicit in (a) what values can occur and (b) which should be treated similarly? Should, e.g., `5|3|NA` be treated like `5|5|NA` or should that be a different group. Number of columns and string vs. numeric should not be a problem.

Comment: a) Any values can occur and this is not important. Basically a number means the presence or absence of proteins in the sample. If there's a number in the Ion Score column, this means that there's a protein. If there isn't a number (NA), this means that there isn't a protein. b) Yes, it should be treated in the same. More or less a number is like TRUE, and NA is like FALSE in a boolean way to see this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the `split` function. To find all combinations of Ion scores I concatenated the index of `NA's` to create a unique string of possibilites. The result is a list, which to me is a better way to store the results for downstream analysis.

```
df <- split(Proteins, drop = T, 
           f = list(apply(Proteins[, -c(1:2)], 1, 
                                    function(x) paste(which(is.na(x)),
                                                      collapse = "") )))

# [[1]]
# N Accession Ion.Score1 Ion.Score2 Ion.Score3
# 1 1      4322          5          5          5
# 
# $`1`
# N Accession Ion.Score1 Ion.Score2 Ion.Score3
# 4 4      2341         NA          5          5
# 
# $`13`
# N Accession Ion.Score1 Ion.Score2 Ion.Score3
# 3 3      2344         NA          5         NA
# 
# $`2`
# N Accession Ion.Score1 Ion.Score2 Ion.Score3
# 2 2       222          5         NA          5
```

Comment: I can't understand your point. Inside that list, how can I find those who haven't got NA and those how have got one or more NA?. I need to export those results to excel.

Comment: Based on your post you wanted to split your data based on which `Ion Score` the protein was missing from (I edited my answer to remove the split on protein ID). Based on `names(df)` you can determine how many times a protein is missing and from what Ion Scores it is missing from. If you want the data split based on the number of times it is missing then it would be better to split the data based on the sum of `NAs` for each protein.

Comment: Yes, but I can have more that one Ion Score missing. I think the list should be a list of lists. I edited my question with a example of what I mean.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you are expecting the output to look like. I think... Given this entry (from your edited post) `3 | 4125      |  NA            | 9          | NA          |  ` you want it to show up three times: The list of missing Ion Score1, Ion Score3, and both( Ion Score1 and Ion Score3). Is that correct?